# Some Random Blender 2.82 question about measure tool

Tags: math, geometry, polygon, blender, angle

I was using blender 2.82 and actually i am pretty new to it and learning it and messing around with tools in it, and when i was using measure tool, i tried to measure angles on monkey face and tried to sum up all the interior angles of one face with 4 sides, but i was not getting that why the sum was coming out to be 355 degrees not 360 degrees as i know that sum of interior angles for polygons with n sides is (n-2)*180 degrees which means it should be 360 degrees as it has four sides but it was rather 355 degrees. I don't if this is some bug and i should report this bug or like i am doing something wrong in this and i need to know something that i don't know. Here are some pictures of the above described situation. Thanks in advance for your reply.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're in 3D space and you're looking at a non-planar face. If you select that face and go to Mesh > Clean up > Make Planar Faces and then re-snap your rulers on the angles, you will get 359, which is still 1° less but that's only due to the fact that the angles don't have decimals.